# html data tables and headers misaligned when using ajax query

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my flask application I've switched from having a logtable built by flask and served to the page on reload to an ajax call.

The ajax is working fine but for some reason the headers and data are misaligned and have different fonts (as below)

[image: New Table please, waiter!]

The html that gets built in flask is built this way:

```
def htmlbuild(data):
    html="<table><th>Time</th><th>Username</th><th>Action</th>"
    for line in data:
        html+= "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (line[1], line[2], line[3])
    html+="</table>"
    return html
```

and in JavaScript/JQuery the table is built this way.

```
(function ajaxLogCalls(){    $.ajax({ url: "{{ url_for('.ajaxLogGrab') }}", dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
        $("#logtable").empty();
        $("#logtable").append("<table><th>Time</th><th>Username</th><th>Action</th>");
        $(data.logs).each(function(i, el) {
            var listem = el.datestamp + "</td><td>" + el.username + "</td><td>" + el.action;
            $("#logtable").append("<tr><td>" + listem + "</td></tr>");
        });
        $("#logtable").append("</table>");
    }
    });
    setTimeout(ajaxLogCalls, 2000)
    })();
```

functionally, they're basically identical.

I've had to create a new div for the table but I can't see any css that would be fighting against this. Plus, as I was targetting by ID I tried as a form and ul rather than a div and got the same result.

The CSS that applies to tables is:

```
th {
background-color: #006099;
color: white;
 }
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
th, td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
padding: 5px;
text-align: left;
}
table {
width: 100%;
}
```

Interestingly when I tried applying something to the new div to change the font size it changed the data but not the headers.. As i said this only seems to happen with the data that's built by ajax.

```
 #logtable {
font: 70px Georgia, sans-serif;
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to what might have happened?

Comment: Can you post the final output somewhere so we can see what that looks like?

Comment: That's what the attached image is.

Comment: Unless it was blocked by the firewall here. Possibly. Let me see if there's anywhere I can put it.

Comment: Great. yeah, it's blocked. As is dropbox, as is everywhere else. Boo.Basically the flask rendered table is fine, all aligned, font at about 20px, the other has the headers correct but the table dividers on the other row are out of whack and the font is really small (ie: the default for the page

Answer (score 0):

Found out the difference but still not sure why. The flask output had no carriage return but the javascript append did, so I made it all into one long string instead and now it renders properly.

```
(function ajaxLogCalls(){    $.ajax({ url: "{{ url_for('.ajaxLogGrab') }}", dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
        $("#logtable").empty();
        var output1 = "<table><tr><th>Time</th><th>Username</th><th>Action</th></tr>"
        $(data.logs).each(function(i, el) {

            var output2 = "<tr><td>" + el.datestamp + "</td><td>" + el.username + "</td><td>" + el.action + "</td></tr>";

            output1 += output2;
        });
        $("#logtable").append(output1 + "</table>");
    }
    });
    setTimeout(ajaxLogCalls, 2000)
    })();
```

Still weird though.